# How to override injection by another instance

Tags: java, inversion-of-control, guice

I have a class which I cannot change:

```
class SomeBean
{
   @Inject private Dep1 dep1;
   @Inject private Dep2 dep2;
   ...
   @Inject private DepN depN;
}
```

I have my class:

```
class MyBean
{
   @Inject@Named("bean1") private SomeBean bean1;
   @Inject@Named("bean2") private SomeBean bean2;
}
```

How could make a module configuration so that `bean1` and `bean2` are injected by different instances which have different dep2 instances, but all other dependencies are the same?

If I were using the spring, I could create a bean in a context file such as:

```
   <bean class="MyBean">
     <property name="bean1">
       <bean class="SomeBean">
         <property name="dep2" ref="dep2InstanceA"/>
       </bean>
     </property>
     <property name="bean2">
       <bean class="SomeBean">
         <property name="dep2" ref="dep2InstanceB"/>
       </bean>
     </property>
   </bean>
```

So that I explicitly override one property, all other autowired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [PrivateModules](https://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/PrivateModule.html) read about [How do I build two similar but slightly different trees of objects?](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions).

Some pseudocode to give you a feeling:

```
class Bean1Module extends PrivateModule
   bind(Dep2.class).to(Dep2A.class)
   bind(SomeBean.class)
   expose(SomeBean.class).annotatedWith("bean1")

class Bean2Module extends PrivateModule
   bind(Dep2.class).to(Dep2B.class)
   bind(SomeBean.class)
   expose(SomeBean.class).annotatedWith("bean2")
```

It might be a bit more lines of code than Spring xml lines but this is typesafe, code complete works without any plugins, you can even put some logic in the module, etc. ;)

Comment: Thanks. Neat. I like guice.

Comment: Direct link:
https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#how-do-i-build-two-similar-but-slightly-different-trees-of-objects